# Is it safe to eat food that was heated in plastic wrap to the point the plastic wrap flamed?

Tags: food-safety, salmon

I accidentally used plastic wrap instead of foil wrap over the salmon in the toaster oven. There was a flame.  When i checked the salmon,  the cling wrap was gone. Did it melt into thge salmon? Is the salmon safe to eat?

Comment: Generally, plastic isn't good to eat and there is almost certainly some on your salmon. If it was a life and death survival situation, I'd eat the part that wasn't touching the plastic. But if you have a toaster oven, it's probably not a life and death situation... Chuck it...

Comment: Plastic wrap is actually acceptable as field wrapping for burns and wounds.  It is sterile as it comes from the manufacturing process, and non-toxic for contact.  So having had it in contact with food when it has not burned, is not a problem.  http://www.acep.org/content.aspx?id=40462

Answer (score 16):

There are multiple types of film wrap, which are different plastics.  No matter what yours was made from, it almost certainly partially burned up, partially melted, and partially had other heat-based reactions leaving unknown remains on your food, possibly including dioxins, which are quite toxic.

In any of these cases, I would not risk finding out.

Discard the fish.

Comment: This answer is right, but just curious why does this get 15 up votes, without anyone leaving one comment? It is kind of a low-knowledgeable question with a relatively obvious answer. I feel fishy reading some really nice answers these days not being recognized as much as something like this getting inexplicable number of up votes.

Comment: @kmc I have long since stopped wondering these things.  The pattern of votes and comments is almost impossible to predict, it seems, and is not related in any way I can understand to the amount of research or depth a particular answer required! :-)

Comment: well I guess you're right. I might think it's common sense not the eat the plastic wrap but people may think otherwise..